What is the relationship between persistence length and timescale?
I have calculated the bending persistence length of a polymer using MD simulations in the nanosecond timescale. The persistence length is long (410 nm) compared to the contour length (40-45 nm). But the equilibrium transition phenomena I am interested in is on the millisecond timescale. I have a coarse grain simulation on the ms timescale but I'm not exactly sure what equations I should be looking at to relate the bending correlations with time.
